# Puppet PowerShell Execution

Tags: powershell, puppet

I have an application which requires a local account to be required for the configuration. I have created a module inside that I have 2 folders:

1. `files`
2. `manifests`

Under manifests init file I have the below code:

```puppet
class xyz {
  exec { ' app_config':
    command => ' C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -file c:\provisioning\modules\xyz\files\config1.ps1 '
  }
}
```

Under files folder there are 2 files:

1. `config1.ps1`
2. `app_execute.bat`

In `config1.ps1` I am creating a local user:

```bsh
$user = $env:COMPUTERNAME/Testing

$Credentials = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PScredential -ArgumentList $user, ("test@3456", | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)

Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Credential $Credentials -ArgumentList " Start-Process C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe -File c:\provisioning\c:\provisioning\modules\xyz\files\app_execute.bat "
```

In `app_execute.bat`

```batch
c:\puppet\app.bat -f c:\puppet\responsefile.rsp
```

The log file shows that the PowerShell file `config1.ps1` got executed successfully, but the application log file is not getting generated, but when executed manually the `config1.ps1` the app will get configured.

Not sure, in `config1.ps1`, I am using a `Start-Process` which will create a separate process using the local account.

I think Puppet is not waiting for the above `config1.ps1` to be completed succesfully.

Not sure why it is coming out without executing fully, Is there any condition, as we need to execute only one file inside init, as I am initiating 2 processes.

Comment: An `exec` resource, which starts a powershell script, which starts a PowerShell process, which starts a CMD process, which runs a batch file (with an invalid path), which runs another batch file, which processes some kind of response file. Wow. Just ... *wow!* My recommendation is: throw it away and start over. Like, from scratch. Consider using [`user` resources](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.6/reference/resources_user_group_windows.html) for creating local users this time.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, Thanks a lot with the input, I will try out the user resources and will check.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers, I used the user resource option, but it is throwing error, I have raised a ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39653659/puppet-local-account-creation-error for the same

Answer (score 1):

For your command, this is what worked for me and I copy it throughout my work with Puppet:

```
command  => 'powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file C:\<path to .ps1>'
```

What's key to remember:

1. You can only use .ps1 files with the -File option here
2. You can add anything Powershell within this .ps1 so utilize the PowerShell ISE to the best of your ability. A great resource to build your powershell scripts.
3. Create a facts.d within the like directory that contains your manifests directory. Then create a batch file that checks if a file or directory exists, which is a simple way of accomplishing the generation of a fact. This might be hard in your case when checking for a user creation, but remember to `ECHO user_creation_need=true` or `=false`
4. Test in a VM. This step is really crucial and I won't go into details, but as long as you can quickly switch back to a known good test state, the successful implementation of your Puppet work will be more certain. Look into Disk2Vhd and VirtualBox.

https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.3/reference/quick_start_user_group.html

Now, creating users is very awesome in Puppet because you don't need any of the directions above. Instead:

```puppet
class user_group_creator {
  group {'Cool People':
    name       => 'Cool People',
    members    => ['User1','User3'],
    ensure     => present,
  }
  user {'User2':
    ensure           => present,
    name             => 'User2',
    password         => 'Password',
    password_max_age => '99999',
    before           => Group['Cool People'],
    groups           => 'Cool People',
 } 
}
```

Let me know how this helps or what you don't understand! Puppet can be a beast at times!