# Puppet Local Account Notify Issue

Tags: puppet

```
user { 'acc1':
  ensure          => present,
  managehome      => true,
  password        => 'Test123',
  groups          => ['Administrators'],
  auth_membership => 'minimum',
  notify          => Exec['app config']
}

exec { 'app config':
  path        => 'c:\\program files (x86)\\app\\bin',
  command     => 'config.bat -f responsefile.rsp',
  refreshonly => true
}
```

The user is getting created, but I need the local account to be used for the app configuration.

The above puppet script is executed by domain account `abc\myname`, and the application requires a local account to be used for the configuration.

So I have created a local account through puppet and using notify to tell exec to use the account created by the puppet. But when it is executed, the application is throwing error: `need a local account or administrator`

In logs the error is `myname is not a local account or administrator`.

I see that `exec` is not using the local user `acc1` created by puppet.

Is there any other way wherein I can direct the `exec` to use a particular local user account to use for configuration.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2):

Specify `user => 'acc1'` in the exec resource: [Resource Type Reference: exec: user](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/type.html#exec-attribute-user).

> So I have created a local account through puppet and using notify to tell exec to use the account created by the puppet.

The `notify` is a *ordering* and *refreshing* mechanic - when resource A notifies resource B, no information is carried between them other than an update to resource B is required. It doesn't specify that resource B *uses* resource A necessarily, it doesn't inherit any properties from the resource A.

Comment: Used the attribute "User" , but getting the below error:           Puppet(err) : Parameter user failed on Exec[app config] : Unable to execute command as other users on Windows at D:\Provisioning\modules\appconfig\manifests\init.pp